# Flexbox Holy Grail layout broken in Chrome - Content overflows flex item

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

I'm trying to produce a variation of the "Holy Grail" layout using Flexbox. The layout works fine in Firefox but in Chrome the inner content breaks out of its flex containers.

Code Pen: https://codepen.io/gregbrowndev/pen/MxRdja

```css
html,
body {
  height: 95%;
}

.app-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  flex: 0 auto;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.content-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1;
  border: solid red 3px;
}

aside {
  flex: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: brown;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.content-block {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: grey;
}

footer {
  flex: 0 auto;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="app-wrapper">
    <header>Header</header>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="content">
        <aside>Aside</aside>
        <main>
          <div class="content-block">Overflowing Child</div>
        </main>
      </div>
      <footer>Footer</footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see in the code snippet, in Chrome, `content-block` breaks out of its parent `main` container and ancestor `content` element (which has the red border). In Firefox, the red border expands in height to accommodate the height of `content-block`.

**Further Details**

In the layout, the `header` should be fixed to the top of the view port (without using fixed positioning) and the `footer` should: stick to the bottom  when the inner `content` height is less then the vh, and scroll off the screen when greater.

To achieve this `content` and `footer` are wrapped in a overflow container, `content-wrapper`, so they can scroll without affecting the header. Additionally, to ensure `content` can fill the space and push the `footer` to the bottom, `content-wrapper` is also made a flex container.

I've read this [useful article](https://moduscreate.com/blog/how-to-fix-overflow-issues-in-css-flex-layouts/) on overflow issues in flex layouts. However, if I implement their solution and make a child '`overflow-container`' (presumably without `display: flex`) then I lose the ability for `content` to fill the space, while if I do make it a flex container I end up with the same problem again.

Comment: can you share a screenshot, maybe its me but I'm not seeing any issue... also add a snippet in the question :)

Comment: @kukkuz that's strange, see if the snippet shows the issue as for me it I see the same problem!

Comment: This seems to be broken in their latest update.